# question about path-convertible, compact and connected

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space. We Write $X$ is path-coverable if there is a continuous and surjective function $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow X$

True or False:  a) If X is path-coverable, then X is compact.
b) If X is path-coverable, then X is connected.
c) If X is compact, then X is path-coverable.
d) If X is connected, then X is path-coverable.

For(a): True: continuous image of a compact sets are compact.   (b) Ture: path-coverable means path-connected, which implies connected.

Can anyone solve part (c) (d), and fix if the answer for (a) and (b) is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct. Hints for the other parts: you probably saw the topologist's sine curve. Use it. Now for compactness, which intuitively means the space is small, why should small imply any form of connectivity? In particular, what is a very small (but not too small) example of a compact space? Can you make it not connected? Extra exercise: if a space is compact and connected must it be path-coverable?

Comment: a compact set might not be continuous?

Comment: 'Continuous set' has no meaning.

Comment: i mean a compact set might not connected?

Comment: Indeed. Think small. Finitely small.

Comment: just a point???

Comment: But not too small.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea